# CSS file isn't properly linked when I change the .html file to a .php

Tags: php, html, css, zurb-foundation

This problem is exclusive to the index.html file, and as I said before, the CSS that works when it's an html, stops working when the extension is changed. I inspected the ref link on both instances and when it's a php, the CSS files end up being the php file itself. I'm assuming that it maybe can't access the css for some weird reason? I'm not sure how that translates to only when it's a php. I've done the same procedure to other pages, and it works fine.

If it means anything, part of what stops working is the Foundation I'm using.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Foundation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
</head>
```

I also found that any href links stop working as well.

Comment: please post the section of code where the css file is being linked.

Comment: Does the url start with localhost or file:// or c:/ ?

Comment: Nope, http://localhost:8888/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is delivered using a wrong MIME type. Try forcing CSS MIME type by setting the headers like below:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Moreover, make sure that, using PHP, you should execute using a server. i.e., the following URL is right:

```
http://domain/path/to/index.php
http://localhost/project/index.php
```

And not:

```
file:///c:/wamp/www/project/index.php
file:///c:/myproject/index.php
file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/index.php
```